# Advertisements in Iphone app 

Tags: iad, ads

I didn't find any good answer for my question anywhere. I'm developing an app for some client, it's a free app that including advertisement banner, but only for some ads that my client chooses. In iAd it is impossible for sure, what about other ad's networks?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most ad networks give you the ability to screen out ads that potentially conflict with your own app, for example you wouldn't want to show ads for a direct competitor.

This [section of the Admob FAQ](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/kb/#adfilters) details the process, though you'd have to log in to test it.

Comment: Thanks, i just can't understan if i have to use ONLY adds from the service i choose(like Admob) or i can enter only my clients add?